# AppCompatActivity remove action bar elevation/shadow with style

Tags: android, android-styles

My app has a minimum SDK 16 and I'm using `AppCompatActivity`, so I need to use `Theme.AppCompat.x` as my base theme.

I know that if I call `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0)`, I can remove the shadow under action bar for each activity.

What I want to do is to apply this effect by using a theme. Any idea to achieve this?

My main style looks like this and the application uses `@style/AppTheme`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: ps, i'm also using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <!-- Pre-lolipop -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!-- remove shadow below action bar -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: the @style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse was what I'm missing, thank you so much, it was magic